# FormBuilder accessing second-level attributes (dot notation)

Tags: mongodb, angular, angular2-forms

I'm using Angular2's FromBuilder to build a query to send to my backend (MongoDB). The problem is, I'm trying to access second-level attributes. For example I have a Song which has a Genres array in it. I want to access genres.hipHop for example but I can't set a form group to genres.hipHop. All I can do is use one word.

Here is an example of a query I want to build

```
{
  "where": {
    "and": [
      {"genres.house": {"exists": "true"}}
    ]
  },
  "order": "created DESC"
};
```

My FormBilder looks like this:

```
this.queryForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  where: this._formBuilder.group({
    and: this._formBuilder.array([
      this._formBuilder.group({
        genres : this._formBuilder.group({  <-- need it be genres.hipHop
          exists: true
        })
      })
    ]),
    order: 'created DESC',
  })
});
```

Which creates:

```
{
  "where": {
    "and": [
      {"genres": {"exists": "true"}} 
    ]
  },
  "order": "created DESC"
};
```

I can't add the .hipHop after genres.

I tried nesting the genres(hipHop) inside of genres but when I send it to my backend, it doesn't recognize hipHop. This is the query that was built:

```
{ "where": { 
  "and": [ 
    { "genres": 
      { "hipHop": { "exists": true } } 
    } 
  ], 
  "order": "created DESC" } 
}
```

This was the error I got:

```
"MongoError: unknown operator: $hipHop\n
```

Here is an example of a song object:

```
{
    "title": "Sweet Talk feat. Quinn XCII (Evan Gartner Remix)",
    "artist": "Academy",
    "audio": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/270500010/stream?client_id=90d140308348273b897fab79f44a7c89",
    "image": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000168676452-qkxqul-t500x500.jpg",
    "download": "http://stereoload.com/academy/quinn-xcii-x-academy-sweet-talk-evan-gartner-remix",
    "url": "http://soundcloud.com/academy401/sweettalkremix",
    "created": "2016-12-13T09:21:28.071Z",
    "genres": {
      "hipHop": 30,
      "house": 30,
      "pop": 40
    },
    "rank": 0
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried define object key as a string `"genres.hipHop"`?

```
this.queryForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  where: this._formBuilder.group({
    and: this._formBuilder.array([
      this._formBuilder.group({
        "genres.hipHop" : this._formBuilder.group({
          exists: true
        })
      })
    ]),
    order: 'created DESC',
  })
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing. Thanks Yury!

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would build the HTML form for this? Having nested groups is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to use the dot notation here, as it won't be a valid key.

Looking at this line in the source:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.1/modules/%40angular/forms/src/form_builder.ts#L75

It looks like Angular iterates over the keys to build the controls.  As you can't do "x.y" as a key in javascript, this fails.

Example

```
var x = {y.z = "a"} //--> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

I think you'll have to make another set of keys inside your genre FormGroup -- one of the keys could be hiphop, for instance.  Which might be what you're looking to do anyway if there are more genres you want to add :)

EDIT:

Example --

```
this.queryForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  where: this._formBuilder.group({
    and: this._formBuilder.array([
      this._formBuilder.group({
        genres : this._formBuilder.group({
          hiphop : this._formBuilder.group({
              exists: true
          })
        })
      })
    ]),
    order: 'created DESC',
  })
});
```

Comment: oh ok, i kind of get it. could you show me a quick example? thanks!

Comment: I'll edit the question with a potential sample -- it would look similar to what you're already doing! :)

Comment: Ohh ok I see. So I tried this but I get an error from my backend :S . Any other ideas?